# How to convert linq selector into predictor

Tags: c#, generics, delegates, lambda

I have a lambda selector, lets say `Func<T, TResult>`. Is it possible to convert it into a predictor (`Func<T, bool>`) using a `TResult` object as reference?

For example, convert

```
x => x.Name
```

into

```
x => x.Name == customerName
```

Comment: Many thanks to Steven, Timwi and Ani. Your answer are all correct. But I can only mark one of yours as the answer. Thanks you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Func<Person, string> projection = x => x.Name;

Func<Person, bool> predicate = x => projection(x) == customerName;
```

Answer (score 5):

Something like this?

```
static Func<TInput, bool> CreatePredicate<TInput, TResult>(Func<TInput, TResult> selector, TResult comparisonValue)
{
    return tInput => selector(tInput).Equals(comparisonValue);
}
```

Usage:

```
Func<Foo, bool> myPredicate = CreatePredicate(x => x.Name, customerName);
```

Could you tell us a bit more about why you want to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I’ll assume that you meant

```
x => x.Name == customerName
```

because `=` is assignment and I think you want comparison.

The answer is:

```
static Func<T, bool> MakePredictor<T>(Func<T, string> lambda,
                                      string customerName)
{
    return x => lambda(x) == customerName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static Predicate<T> Predicate<T, TResult>(Func<T, TResult> selector, TResult value) {
  return Predicate(selector, value, EqualityComparer<TResult>.Default);
}

static Predicate<T> Predicate<T, TResult>(Func<T, TResult> selector, TResult value, IEqualityComparer<TResult> comparer) {
  if(selector == null) {
    throw new ArgumentNullException("selector");
  } else if(comparer == null) {
    throw new ArgumentNullException("comparer");
  }

  return x => comparer.Equals(selector(x), value);
}
```